# FACEBOOK Re-Login Not work Properly

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

When I Login First Time with Facebook it work Properly and Redirect To another Page,but when I perform sign out operation with Facebook Account And Re-login With Facebook It can Not work Properly till Relaunch application.

If I Relaunch Application it perform Login properly.

Comment: you need to clear the token information of facebook and close the facebook session while logout with facebook.

Answer (score 0):

This method will help you to clear token information and logout from facebook.

```
public static void callFacebookLogout(Context context) {
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null) {

    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        //clear your preferences if saved
    }
}else {

    session = new Session(context);
    Session.setActiveSession(session);

    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        //clear your preferences if saved

}
```

}